# Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 16384 (char 16383)

Tags: python, websocket

I am using websocket and am trying to parse the response object.

```
websocket = create_connection(url, headers=self.headers)
while True:
            try:
                result = websocket.recv()
                toJson = json.loads(result)
                print(toJson)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                break
```

Doing json.loads gives `Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 16384 (char 16383)`

I am trying to extract json response from websocket recv.

Comment: The number (2^14) gives a hint that your JSON might have gotten truncated or fragmented into multiple parts. Is it continued in the next `recv()` call?

Comment: I'd like to expand on Klaus' correct answer.  TCP is a streaming protocol, not packets.  The buffers that are sent can be combined or chopped up for many reasons.  You might receive them in many pieces.  You need to keep reading until you get some "end" signal.  For JSON, that's usually a newline or a closing bracket.

Comment: I suggest you to print `result[16380:16390]` and see if it is a malformed json string.